# Splitting strings in python based on index

Tags: python, string

This sounds pretty basic but I ca't think of a neat straightforward method to do this in Python yet

I have a string like `"abcdefgh"` and I need to create a list of elements picking two characters at a time from the string to get `['ab','cd','ef','gh']`.

What I am doing right now is this

```
output = []

for i in range(0,len(input),2):
  output.append(input[i:i+2])
```

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: related: [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/4279)

Comment: I probably just don't like the for loop there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [2]: s = 'abcdefgh'

In [3]: [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
Out[3]: ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, if you hate `for`

```
>>> s='abcdefgh'
>>> map(''.join, zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']
```

Comment: I _just_ thought of exactly that way.

Comment: Or `map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*2))`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a nicer way?

Sure.  List comprehension can do that.

```
def n_chars_at_a_time(s, n=2):
  return [s[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(s), n)]
```

should do what you want.  The `s[i:i+n]` returns the substring starting at `i` and ending `n` characters later.

```
n_chars_at_a_time("foo bar baz boo", 2)
```

produces

```
['fo', 'o ', 'ba', 'r ', 'ba', 'z ', 'bo', 'o']
```

in the python REPL.

For more info see [Generator Expressions and List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

> Two common operations on an iterator’s output are
>
> 1. performing some operation for every element,
> 2. selecting a subset of elements that meet some condition.
>
> For example, given a list of strings, you might want to strip off trailing whitespace from each line or extract all the strings containing a given substring.
>
> List comprehensions and generator expressions (short form: “listcomps” and “genexps”) are a concise notation for such operations...